# Change the width by title

Tags: javascript

I want make the width of fixed sized element 300 pixel. What is wrong with the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () { 
    $('@title="Title Name"').css("width", "300px");
});
```

Comment: What documentation are you following that is recommending the ancient `@` syntax?

Comment: I asked a friend and he offered this. I tried some other codes too but they didn't work for it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@` and the useless parenthesis.

If your td has an attribute named `title`, you may do this :

```
$.ready(function () { 
   $('td [title~="Title Name"]').parent().css("width", "300px");
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. I edited my question. I try to edit the element's width which is in a cell of a table.

Comment: This isn't clear. Maybe my edited answer will work for you. If not, please add the HTML of your problem in the question to make it clearer.

Comment: It didn't work.The code is very complicated. Because the code belongs to an webpart in sharepoint. How can I change the width of the elements which elements has the title contains "Title Name"?

Comment: From your last comment, my edited answer should do it. But you should probably build a reduced example of the HTML, no need to put the real one.

Comment: I found the problem source. But I think I can't solve it with javascript. <div>....dialogHeight:500px;dialogWidth:500px;....</div>

Answer (score 0):

You set id or class for td and then use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tdID").css({width:"300px"})
})
```

or you use inline style

for example

```
<td style="width:300px"></td>
```